# How to run Xamarin Android app from Visual Studio?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, adb

Coming from Android Studio I have already pushed apps to my Android device before (drivers and developer settings all setup), and running `adb devices` shows my device in the list.

[image: adb devices list]

What am I missing in order to be able to see my device in the Start list in Visual Studio for my Xamarin project?

[image: Start list]

Right now it just shows two virtual devices. How do I get *my physical* device to show up and deploy my app there?

Comment: If before open VS you were in Android studio, maybe the adb server was attached to AS. try to quit AS and VS. restart adb and then run VS.

Comment: No joy even if AS is never even opened. Your comment does make me suspect maybe the `adb` services are different (different SDK paths). WIll report back! Can you however confirm, I should be expecting to see my device in the Debug targets list (ie the Start button's list)?

Comment: What API level your app targets? What version of Android you are running

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removed Android SDK and references in environmental variables, uninstalled Xamarin and reinstalled and let the installer create and download the SDK. Lo and behold it started to work.

[image: my device appears (Nexus 5X)]

Not sure what weird configuration I had prior.

Comment: It must be a way to solve this more democratic... 